# django: redirect to another page after download is triggered

Tags: python, django

I would like the user to be redirected to another page after the download of his file is triggered. How should I do this? Below is my code on how the download is triggered. Alternatively, how could I parse the data frame created in the first web page to the web page the user is redirected to then trigger the download? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import *
from .functions import *
from . import models

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # upload file
        file=request.FILES['excelfile']
        df=createDF(file)

        # write to xlsx and trigger download
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefile.xlsx")
        df.to_excel(response, index=False)
        return response
    # render form for upload
    return render(request, 'webpage/index.html')
```

Comment: You could use redirect to make it happen. [Official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view for the dataframe you mentioned, register that view in the urls.py file and you can use this new view in the redirect method after something happen, like after use click on download button redirect to new page with dataframe and start download or maybe download already started in the last view.

```
def dataframe(request):
    # code to generate your dataframe, not sure how it works with your data.
    return render(request, 'your_dataframe_template.html')
```

Inside urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dataframeurl/', views.dataframe, name='dataframecoolname') # use some better name in the name argument 
]
```

Now you can use `name` argument inside a view with redirect method.

```
# the redirect would be something like this
def download_view(request):
    # some logic you want, then...
    return redirect(dataframecoolname) # must be the same name argument you used in the url
```